# javascript expression to check if array includes only a specified type

Tags: javascript, function, expression, typeof

Hello everyone I struggling to create an expression to check if a specific array includes only a specified type values.Here is what I tried :

```
const isArrayOfType = (arr, type) =>
  arr.forEach((item) => typeof item == type) ? true : false;

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const typ = 'number';

console.log(isArrayOfType(arr, typ));
```

The main goal is to not use return in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` doesnt return anything, I think you're looking for `every` (and the ternary operator is unecessary as it already returns a boolean)

```js
const isArrayOfType = (arr, type) =>
  arr.every((item) => typeof item == type);

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const typ = 'number';

console.log(isArrayOfType(arr, typ));
console.log(isArrayOfType(["one",2,3], typ));
```